# Problem copying over an object that was created by live sketch in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, live-trace

I had a sketch that I created. Then scanned it and did a live trace in Illustrator CS5. I don't really need all of the drawing but there is a hamburger that I wanted to make its own project. So I selected the background, deleted that. Now I selected the burger

[image]

And did command + C to copy. Then pasted into a new document. But the paths appear to me messed up and the color is not copied over either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your screenshot, it looks like you used the Path Selection Tool to select the sketch you want to copy. How about you use the Selection Tool which is the black arrow to the left of the Path Selection Tool?

Comment: Ok yes that works. I used the black arrow and also isolated the group. Then I copied and pasted. But the color did not transfer over. Any idea why?

Comment: Weird, copy-pasting should work fine. Have you tried grouping the whole thing and copying everything without isolating?

Comment: yes I ended up trying that later and that did get the color.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably activated the "Outline" option.

Try this:
Open "View" > "Preview" or just cmd + Y

Comment: Good guess. That is not what happened this time though. But thank you.